# Unreadable dark text on tag pages.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tags

On tag pages such as https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism, the text "tag has no wiki summary, would you like to" is unreadably dark.

However, the "help us create it?" part looks good.

Comment: closing so the community user doesn't bump it anymore

Answer (score 1):

The fix will be in the next deployment